# save a string in dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, deserialization

I have in following string:

[{"key":"cod1","value":["RR4","RR6"]},{"key":"cod2","value":["RR2","RR3"]},{"key":"cod3","value":["RR1","RR2"]}]

and I want to save it in a dictionary like this:

Dictionary<string, List>

The project is made in C# and to try to do it I use the following statement:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dic = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(ss);
```

But I get this error:

"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1.\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureArrayContract(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)\r\n   at operationWebAPI.Repository.TransferLadleRepository.LastEvents() in C:\Users\raulm\Documentos\Proyectos\SOSteelShop\Backend\operationWebAPI\Repository\TransferLadleRepository.cs:line 1164\r\n   at operationWebAPI.Controllers.TransferLadleController.GetLastEvents() in C:\Users\raulm\Documentos\Proyectos\SOSteelShop\Backend\operationWebAPI\Controllers\TransferLadleController.cs:line 229"

I can't find how to solve the problem. Can you help me? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Are you saying that :
`ss = "[{\"key\":\"cod1\",\"value\":[\"RR4\",\"RR6\"]},{\"key\":\"cod2\",\"value\":[\"RR2\",\"RR3\"]},{\"key\":\"cod3\",\"value\":[\"RR1\",\"RR2\"]}]"`
Because you can't actually set ss to a string value without escaping those other double-quotes.

Comment: Can you please show how the resulting dictionary for provided json should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root json element is array, so the data can be represented as collection of `Dictionary<string, JToken>`:

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, JToken>>>(json);
```

But I suggest to introduce a class representing data and processing it correspondingly:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<string> Value { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

> JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array

Not sure if it will work but you can try that

[JsonArrayAttrribute Usage in C# Code ( Json.Net )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201422/jsonarrayattrribute-usage-in-c-sharp-code-json-net)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can extract data as a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> dic = JArray.Parse(json)
    .ToDictionary(k=> (string) k["key"], k=> k["value"].ToObject<List<string>>());
```

but since you have a collection , it is more natural to extract the data as a collecton

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>>>(json);
    
    //how to use
    
List<string> cod2 = list.Where(l =>l.Key=="cod2").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```